# Указатель на тип char, нюансы

Tags: c++, указатели

Мне не понять

```
char *name[] = { "la la","la" };
cout << name << endl; // этот выдаёт адрес первого элемента

char *name1 = "la la";
cout << name1 << endl; // а этот самого "la la"
```

Почему первый вариант выдаёт адрес, а не полный строковый литерал "la la"?
Ведь `cout` перегружен, так что вместо адреса выдаёт полное значение пока не встретит `\0`.

Comment: Перегружен не `cout`, а `operator<<` для `std::ostream`.

Comment: poniatno budu znat.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Потому что на самом деле `name` — это указатель на массив, а не указатель на `char`. Хотите вывести первый элемент массива — пишите

```
cout << name[0] << endl;
```

Comment: `name` — это массив, а не указатель на массив. В строке `cout << name` происходит неявное преобразование массива к указателю на первый элемент массива, т.е. к типу `char **`, который затем неявно преобразуется к `const void *`

Answer (score 4):

В случае `char *name1`, `name1` — это указатель на `char`, т.е. строка, которая и выводится.

А в первом случае `char *name[]`, `name` — это массив указателей на строки. Поэтому выводится адрес этого массива.

Comment: balshoi spasibo.